# Full height video header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a header responsive with video background like [this](http://markup.themewagon.com/titan/index_mp_fullscreen_video_background.html)

But I don't want to embed youtube or something else. I just want a short video as a background and for it to be responsive.

Here is my code so far. My problem is that it is not sticking to full height when I test on mobile, tablet, etc.

```
<header>
    <video poster="pic.jpg" loop="loop" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" volume="0">
        <source src="pic.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</header>

header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
video {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: auto;
```

}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U6Kw.jpg The problem.

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: What problem are you running into?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but you shoudl try using the units "vh" and "vw" which stand for "viewport hight" and "viewport width".  If you set an element to `100vh` it will be 100% the height of the viewport.

Comment: Doesn't stick full height when i test  for mobile,tablet,etc.

Comment: Well that music was a terrible suprise.

Comment: What do u mean? Guys i put here a demo to see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WEdBxv

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<header>
   <video poster="pic.jpg" loop="loop" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" volume="0">
    <source src="http://d.pr/v/DEyST/5QDjeczO+" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</header>
```

CSS

```
    video {
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    html {
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
      font-size: 150%;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .viewport-header {
      position: relative;
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    h1 {
      font-family: 'Syncopate', sans-serif;
      color: #4a3a27;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 3vw;
      line-height: 1.2;
      font-size: 3vw;
      text-align: center;
      span {
        display: block;
        font-size: 10vw;
        letter-spacing: -1.3vw;
      }
    }

    main {
      display: none;
      width: 80vw;
      left: 10%;
      height: 40vh;
      overflow: auto;
      background: rgba(black, 0.66);
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      padding: 1rem;
    }
```

Source: [code](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/jmXapj?editors=1100)

Comment: Thank you for effort but this is Fixed fullpage i want to be only header. just like in that example from above. http://markup.themewagon.com/titan/index_mp_fullscreen_video_background.html